# Scala.JS configuration for Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I tried posting this question to Scala Users but no reply yet. How does one go about working with the new experimental Scala 3 with Scala.JS? I can’t find cogent instructions.

Shockingly there’s nothing I can find on this topic on the Internet.

For example I’ve read (and verified in the Scala 3 source code) that there’s no plugin as the integration is compiled into the dotc compiler. So what I am I suppose to do with the instructions on the Scala.js website that instruct me to add a plugin to the build files?

Answer (score 10):

You follow exactly the same instructions as for Scala 2. The *only* thing you change is `scalaVersion` to some 3.x version.

There is no *compiler* plugin, but there is still an *sbt* plugin. So nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you. And thank you for putting this answer when it can be found by those searching. Is the Sbtplugin for activating the Scala.JS linker?

Comment: The linker, yes, as well as running/testing with a JavaScript runtime instead of a JVM.